# How do I copy raw blocks on same disk using dd?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, dd, data-transfer, macos-highsierra

I want to move physical blocks from one part of a hard disk to another part of the same disk.  I've tried using `dd` on macOS High Sierra, but no data is transferring.

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/disk2 bs=512k count=16777216 skip=916709376 seek=1893461391
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes transferred in 0.000022 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

So I'm trying to move 16,777,216 512 kB blocks starting from position 916,709,376 to position 1,893,461,391.  I've also tried including `of=/dev/disk2` but the results were the same.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: I really wish people would actually be *helpful* instead of ghost downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

`dd` interprets many parameters (including `count`, `skip`, and `seek`) as numbers of blocks, not numbers of bytes. As a result, it's trying to skip about 480 terabytes into /dev/disk2, and I suspect disk2 isn't that big.

Did you mean those values to be in bytes? If so, there's a problem: the `seek` value is an odd number (and the GCD of the three numbers is 1), so I think you'd have to specify a block size of one byte... which is going to make it run very slow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'll think on this a bit.  The sizes are based on the partition table from `sudo gpt show /dev/disk2`, which I thought were blocks.  The disk is 1TB in size.  Basically, I'm trying to move a bunch of partitions to the end of the drive by physically moving their data, then updating the partition table.  This will leave a lot of unallocated space in the middle of the drive, which I can use to expand a partition size.

Comment: @MicahRøckstårHenning I believe the `gpt show` lists positions and sizes in 512-byte "sectors", so switching the blocksize to 512 might make it work. But I have a reservation about placing the partition at an odd-number offset -- many modern drives actually have 4kB sectors, so you normally want things at multiples of that (which'd be a multiple of 8 512-byte old-style sectors). I'd recheck your placement calculations.